# symfony dev.log in prod

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I've similar quesitons here in stackoverflow but haven't seen an answer.

I currently have dev.log and prod.log in my production environment and I don't understand why. I should only have prod.log.

My dev.log only contains this (repeated every 2 minutes):

```
[2017-04-21 17:50:02] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2017-04-21 17:50:02] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT e0_.id AS id0, e0_.name AS name1, e0_.progress AS progress2, e0_.path AS path3, e0_.data AS data4, e0_.created_at AS created_at5, e0_.updated_at AS updated_at6, (SELECT COUNT(e1_.id) AS dctrn__1 FROM export e1_ WHERE e1_.progress > 0 AND e1_.progress < 100) AS sclr7, e0_.organization_id AS organization_id8, e0_.owner_id AS owner_id9 FROM export e0_ WHERE e0_.progress = 0 HAVING sclr7 = 0 LIMIT 1 [] []
[2017-04-21 17:50:02] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
```

Here are my config_dev.yml and config_prod.yml monolog configs:

**config_dev:**

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    main:
      type:  stream
      path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
      level: debug
```

**config_prod:**

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    main_critical:
      type:         fingers_crossed
      action_level: critical
      handler:      buffered_critical
    buffered_critical:
      type:    buffer
      handler: swift_critical
    swift_critical:
      type:       swift_mailer
      from_email: %error_mail_sender%
      to_email:   %error_mail_recipients%
      subject:    An error occurred
      level:      debug
    main_error:
      type:         fingers_crossed
      action_level: error
      handler:      grouped_error
    grouped_error:
      type:    group
      members: [streamed]
    streamed:
      type:  stream
      path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
      level: debug
```

I notice the log shows that a console command happens, and there's a cronjob which runs a command every two minutes, but I don't know why this goes to dev.log...

Thanks a lot for your help,
Cheers

Comment: By default, Symfony commands run in the dev environment.  Add --env=prod to your crontab. http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. By explaining my problem, I hadn't thought about symfony commands log until I wrote this issue. I added --env=prod and solved this. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cerad your comment is the answer, put it where it belongs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default, Symfony Commands are executed in the Dev environment that's why it stores all kinds of logs in the dev.log file using your dev environment configurations for logging.

you need to use `--env=prod` flag with your Symfony command to explicitly tell Symfony to run this command in prod environment.

NOTE:
so if you are running command via cron add the `--env=prod` flag at the end of a command.

this answer is an explanation of @cerad comment.