# Symony 4 command: log in production

Tags: symfony, logging, symfony4, monolog

I have a Symfony command which is executed under a cron entry and I need some log in production environment.

As [I read here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/logging/monolog_console.html) in production, for console commands, verbosity level is related to log level shown, so I tried to configure monolog to show *"notice"* level.

My problem is, log is never written in *prod* environment.

This is my command:

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
class MyCommand extends Command
{
    private $logger;
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $this->logger->notice('### HELLO ###');
    }
}
```

And this is `config/packages/prod/monolog.yml`, see that action_level is set to *notice*:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            path:  '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
            action_level: notice
            handler: nested
            excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
            buffer_size: 50 # How many messages should be saved? Prevent memory leaks
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: php://stderr
            level: debug
            formatter: monolog.formatter.json
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
```

A file `var/log/prod.log` never appears.

*Note*: according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858477/761076), commands are always run in dev environment, but the log entries don't appear in *dev.log* either.

Comment: What are the permissions on the `/var/log` directory?

Comment: They are `drwxrwxr-x` , `dev.log` file is written correctly in same directory

Comment: That seems fine. Also check the directory owner?

Comment: `user www-data`, Apache should be able to write, as is able to write in cache directory or able to write `dev.log`

Comment: try commenting-out the handler setting in main, likely sending them to stderr at present